# A 'loud' scheduling app

Tags: android, time-management, reminders

I need an application to help enforce a daily routine.

For example:

- **7am** - Should be out of bed.
- **7:30am** - Should be doing the dishes.
- **8am** - Should be leaving the house.

The application should interrupt any other applications, and forcibly buzz.

Also  - I'd like to be able to set holidays - so it's easy to remove the group of activities, without having to delete each one.

Comment: There are several applications that provide [speech notifications for calendar events](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=talking+calendar+app#newwindow=1&q=talking+calendar+app) instead of buzzing. I use [Talking Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kashif.talkingcalendarplus&hl=en) on my Android phone.